# Can I feed Tilapia with Millipedes?

Tags: aquaponics

I have plenty of millipedes in my garden, I am planning an aquaponics system (starting to build it).

Are millipedes suitable food for Tilapia? I worry that the hard shell will damage their intestine.

I am talking about those millipedes
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the [yellow spotted millipede](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpaphe_haydeniana), which exudes cyanide as a self defense. [Some people](http://www.bt.cdc.gov/agent/cyanide/basics/facts.asp) will smell the cyanide, which smells like almonds when handling these millipedes, though not everyone is able detect it.

I don't know what the exposure would be to a fish eating one of these, but [studies have been conducted on the effects on tilapia of environmental exposure to cyanide](http://recent-science.com/index.php/rrst/article/viewfile/5201/2663).

The risk might be a moot point, however. The black and yellow markings signal potential predators that this "bug" might not be good to eat - the fish might avoid them.

At any rate, it doesn't seem like it would be a good idea to feed these to the tilapia in your aquaponics system.

Comment: Thanks for that. Not the answer I wanted to hear though, I feel bad to throw all this "meat" away.

Comment: Well, they are doing the good work in your garden breaking down dead organic material. Why not raise worms to feed the tilapia?

Comment: the millipedes are actually doing such a good work that they manage to break down the seeds too... I will for sure have a look at the worms side.

Answer (score 2):

Tilapia will eat those. But unlike pill bugs or BSFL, I don't think they are particularly fond of them. Some of my tilapia (mainly wild-caught Mozambiques) won't eat them at all and those that do (mainly the Niles) seem to loose interest before long.